# Separate rows on multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame where multiple columns hold multiple values.
Imagine the following data.table:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("123456", "234567", "345678"))
df$date <- list(c("010122", "020222"), c("050522", "060622"))
df$street = list(c("A Street", "B Street"), c("C street", "D Street"), c("E Street", "F Street"))
df$nr = list(c("1", "2"), c("1", "2"), c("1", "2"))
```

The data frame then looks like this:

```
id      date                   street                      nr 
123456  c("010122", "020222")  c("A Street", "B Street")   c("1", "2")                
234567  c("030322", "040422")  c("C Street", "D Street")   c("1", "2")
345678  c("050522", "060622")  c("E Street", "F Street")   c("1", "2")
```

I want to be able to separate the rows, so that the df looks like this:

```
id          date       street     nr 
123456      010122     A Street   1
123456      020222     B Street   2
234567      030322     C Street   1
234567      040422     D Street   2
345678      050522     E Street   1
345678      060622     F Street   2
```

`seperate_rows` only takes two columns as input. I tried seperating rows on multiple columns with pipe %>%, but it produces all possible combinations. Does anyone know how to produce only the 6 rows?

Compared to this question ([tidyr use separate_rows over multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922857/tidyr-use-separate-rows-over-multiple-columns)) I am looking to separate values from all columns to the rows. See the desired table.

EDIT: I just updated the df. Sorry for the mistake, guys

Comment: Seems like the data posted doesn't work.

Comment: See the [first answer of that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72130131/5635580)

Answer (score 0):

Using this data

```
df <- data.frame(id = (c("123456", "234567", "345678")), 
                 date = c(c("010122", "0202222"), c("030322", "040422"), c("050522", "060622")),
                 street1 = c("A Street", "B Street"), street2 = c("C street", "D Street"), street3 = c("E Street", "F Street"),
nr = c(c("1", "2"), c("1", "2"), c("1", "2")))
```

thats work for me

```
df %>% separate_rows(street1, street2, street3)
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   id     date    street1 street2 street3 nr   
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
 1 123456 010122  A       C       E       1    
 2 123456 010122  Street  street  Street  1    
 3 234567 0202222 B       D       F       2    
 4 234567 0202222 Street  Street  Street  2    
 5 345678 030322  A       C       E       1    
 6 345678 030322  Street  street  Street  1    
 7 123456 040422  B       D       F       2
```

Comment: But this does not correspond to the dataframe I am looking for...

Comment: please update your data.frame. I can't load it due to several errors.

Comment: EDIT, just updated the dataframe. Hope you can see my problem now